# Listbox selectedIndexChanged doesn't fire when selecting an item from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, listbox

When I add an listItem to my listbox manually, the selectedIndexChanged fires.  When I use a datatable it does not.  Here's my code.

```
ASPX
<asp:ListBox ID="lstProc" runat="server" Rows="3" CssClass="lstProc"    AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="lstProc_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectionMode="Single" Visible="true" EnableViewState="True"  >     <asp:ListItem>HI</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

C#
lstProc.DataSource = dtProcedures;
lstProc.DataTextField = "ProcName";
lstProc.DataValueField = "slotID";
lstProc.DataBind();
lstProc.Items.Add("HELP");
```

Also when I click on the listitem, "HELP", it works but when I click on an item from the datatable the autopostback works but does not enter the selectedIndexchanged.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please provide info in what method you sets lstProc properties

Comment: <asp:ListBox ID="lstProc" runat="server" Rows="3" DataValueField="slotID" DataTextField="procName" CssClass="lstProc" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="lstProc_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        SelectionMode="Single" Visible="true" >
                        <asp:ListItem>HI</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox>

Comment: I also noticed that when I changed the viewstate to enabled, it worked.  The reason I had disabled the viewstate, I was having an issue where the viewstate could not be loaded.